# if condition at cycling number

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, if-statement

While having a `loop` with 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 ... there are two directions for instance from number 4 forwarding 4 5 0 1 2 3 ... and backward 4 3 2 1 0 5 ... . How would the if algorithm for detecting of forwarding or backward look like if values are like actual 2 next 3, or actual 5 next 0.

I'm looking for a simple if that will check

```
if (actual > next && ?jump from last/first?) { 
  forwarding
} else {
  backward
}
```

Any ideas how to detect forward or backward?

Comment: can you post your loop?

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 Do you know what pseudo-code is?

Comment: Is the code always going to be +1 or -1 difference or some other pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$forward = ($actual < $next);
if (abs($actual-$next) != 1) $forward = !$forward;
```

Start off assuming it is forward if *actual* is less than *next*. Then check the difference between *actual* and *next* - if it's not one, you're on the boundary, so the result is the opposite of what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, works like a charm! Lightweight code that makes a complex detection easy in a smart way.